# NSManaged and computed properties

Tags: swift, core-data

In CoreData I'm using several properties like so:

```
class Taxes: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var rateValue: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged var typeValue: NSNumber
```

But to use the properties I first have to convert `rate` and `type`:

```
    enum Values: Int {
        case high = 2
        case low  = 1
        case none = 0

        init(value: NSNumber) {
            switch value.intValue {
            case 2  : self = .high
            case 1  : self = .low
            default : self = .none
        }
    }

    var rate: Decimal      { return rateValue as Decimal }
    var type: Taxes.Values { return Taxes.Values(value: typeValue) }
```

This works, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use the `NSManaged` properties without having to create a set of computed properties. Or perhaps there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can remove the enum's init and use the usual `Taxes.Values(rawValue: typeValue)` constructor for enums.

If you want to use another type than stored in CoreData you have to compute it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating computed properties to map Swift enums is the usual way because Core Data doesn't support Swift enum types.

However you can shorten the code by declaring the numeric values as scalar types

```
class Taxes: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var typeValue: Int32

    enum Values: Int32 {
        case none = 0, low, high
    }

    var type: Taxes.Values { 
        get { return Taxes.Values(rawValue: typeValue)! }
        set { typeValue = newValue.rawValue }
    }
}
```